# Parsing this xml

Tags: c#, xml

I tried a lot of codes but nothing worked.
I have XML:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>first title</title>
        <publisher>first publisher</publisher>
        <description>first description</description>
        <published>1410</published>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>second book</title>
        <publisher>second publisher</publisher>
        <description>second description</description>
        <published>1914</published>
    </book>
    [another book]
    [another book2]
</books>
```

And I want input like this:

```
first title | first publisher | first description | 1410
second title | second publisher | second descirpion | 1914
[another books]
```

"My" Code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"5.xml");
            var entries = from e in xdoc.Descendants("book")
                          select new
                          {
                              Title = (string)e.Element("title"),
                              Description = (string)e.Element("description")
                          };
//I DON'T KNOW WHAT IT DO, I FOUND THIS BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT NEXT
```

I can parse first book but i can't parse multiple. Sorry for language.

Comment: do you want write this values into text file ? or just an output like this?

Comment: I want to add output to database, but I can handle this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an XDocument you may try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("5.xml");
        var books = doc.Descendants("book");
        foreach (var book in books)
        {
            string title = book.Element("title").Value;
            string publisher = book.Element("publisher").Value;
            string description = book.Element("description").Value;
            string published = book.Element("published").Value;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", title, publisher, description, published);
        }
    }
}
```

If on the other hand the XML you are trying to parse is very big and cannot fit into memory it is better to use an `XmlReader` which will allow you to process it record by record:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("5.xml"))
        {
            string title = null, publisher = null, description = null, published = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "book")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", title, publisher, description, published);
                }

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "title")
                {
                    title = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "publisher")
                {
                    publisher = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "description")
                {
                    description = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "published")
                {
                    published = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach you can deal with arbitrary large XML files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to parse your XML

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("5.xml");

var books = (from b in xDoc.Descendants("book")
                select new
                {
                    title = (string) b.Element("title"),
                    publisher = (string) b.Element("publisher"),
                    despription = (string) b.Element("description"),
                    published = (string) b.Element("published")
                }).ToList();

foreach (var book in books)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}  |{3}",book.title,book.publisher,book.despription,book.published);
}
```